# C# Arraylist out of range

Tags: c#, arraylist, count, outofrangeexception

Consider the my following code:

```
for (int a = 0; a < isim.Count; a++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nu[a] + "\t" + isim[a] + "\t" +mail[a]);
}
```

Here are my execution results : [image]

Comment: *and my full code :* No full code!

Comment: Do `nu[]` and `mail[]` have **same** or **large** size than `isim[]`? if not that might be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are not checking to see if `nu[]` and `mail[]` are at least as large as `isim[]`.

At least not in the code fragment you supplied.  Provide more details on the error and more of a code sample if you want a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList mail = new ArrayList();
isim.Add("mail0@gmail.com");
isim.Add("mail1@yandex.com");
isim.Add("mail2@hotmail.com");
isim.Add("mail3@gmail.com");
isim.Add("mail4@gmail.com");
```

Instead of adding to the `isim` arraylist you should add them to `mail` arraylist.

```
ArrayList mail = new ArrayList();
mail.Add("mail0@gmail.com");
mail.Add("mail1@yandex.com");
mail.Add("mail2@hotmail.com");
mail.Add("mail3@gmail.com");
mail.Add("mail4@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have more elements in isim than mu. All mail addresses are being stored in isim. Check your code.